# App signed key did not change after Upgrade signed key playstore

Tags: java, android, google-play

We need to upload our app to other app stores, so the signing key of our app must be the same in all of them so that users can update it.

At first we uploaded an app bundle and the Play Console signed it with its own key and we couldn't update it on other app stores.

At this stage, the App signing key certificate was different from the Upload key certificate.

Then we generated a .zip file from the keystore file we generated with Android Studio using the pepk.jar tool and uploaded it to the Play Console in the App integrity >> Upgrade your app signing key section.

We generated this .zip file using the following command that was mentioned in the Play Console:

$ java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=android_studio_keystore.jks --alias= android_studio_keystore_alias --output=output.zip  --signing-keystore= android_studio_keystore.jks --signing-key-alias= android_studio_keystore_alias --encryptionkey=*************
To do this, we set both keystore and signing-keystore entries to be the same as the .jks file we created with Android Studio.

At this stage, the App signing key certificate was the same as the Upload key certificate.

Then we uploaded a new version of the app bundle and it was published. But we still can't update it with other apps store version because their signed key is different.

We downloaded the latest version APK from the App Bundle Explorer in the Play Console and found its certificate fingerprint using the keytool -printcert -jarfile apkfile.apk command, which was different from the certificate fingerprint displayed in the Play Console.

Then, for comparison, we generated a signed APK using Android Studio and the keystore we created and viewed its certificate fingerprint with the same keytool... command. Its information is the same as the information displayed on the App integrity in the Play Console.

It seems after the upgrade signed key with java keystore, the Play Console app bundle didn't sign with the new upload key.

i expecting same with java keystore

Comment: I would not rely on key tool, it is outdated. Use `apksigner` from Android SDK instead, it has also the option to display the signer certificate hashes.